# How can we distribute compiled source code if it is specific to the hardware it was compiled on?

Tags: c++, operating-system, frameworks, compiled

Suppose we take a compiled language, for example, `C++`. Now let's take an example Framework, suppose `Qt`. `Qt` has it's source code publically available and has the options for users to download the binary files and let users use their API. My question is however, when they compiled their code, it was compiled to their specific HardWare, Operating System, all that stuff. I understand how many Software Require recompilation for different types of Operating Systems (Including 32 vs 64bit) and offer multiple downloads on their website, however how does it not go even further to suggest it is also Hardware Specific and eventually result in the redistribution of compiled executes extremely frustrating to produce?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, and what you want to know. What do you mean with `however how does it not go even further to suggest it is also Hardware Specific`?

Comment: I thought that when you compiled some source code, it created instructions that were specific to the CPU hardware. Would that not suggest that if I created an executable in C++ that I was required to give it to someone else who also has the ware Hardware as I have?

Comment: Yes, you compile your application for a certain architecture. And depending on the chosen architecture the compiler will translate the source code to a certain set of CPU instruction. And that binary then can run on any CPU compatible to that specified architecture. So yes the one who wants to run that binary has to have hardware that supports that instruction set. But what's the problem about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code gets compiled to a target base CPU (e.g. 32-bit x86, x86_64, or ARM), but not necessarily a **specific** processor like the Core i9-10900K.   By default, the compiler typically generates the code to run on the widest range of processors. And Intel and AMD guarantee forward compatibility for running that code on newer processors.  Compilers often offer switches for optimizing to run on newer processors with new instruction sets, but you rarely do that since not all your customers have that config. Or perhaps you build your code twice (once for older processors, and an optimized build for newer processors).

There's also a concept called cross-compiling.  That's where the compiler generates code for a completely different processor than it runs on.  Such is the case when you build your iOS app on a Mac. The compiler itself is an x86_64 program, but it's generating ARM CPU instruction set to run on the iPhone.

Code gets compiled and linked with a certain set of OS APIs and external runtime libraries (including the C/C++ runtime).  If you want your code to run on Windows 7 or Mac OSX Maverics, you wouldn't statically link to an API that only exists on Windows 10 or Mac OS Big Sur.  The code would compile, but it wouldn't run on the older operating systems.  Instead, you'd do a workaround or conditionally load the API if it is available. Microsoft and Apple provides the forward compatibility of providing those same runtime library APIs to be available on later OS releases.

Additionally Windows supports running 32-bit processes on 64-bit chips and OS. Mac can even emulate x86_64 on their new ARM based devices coming out later this year.  But I digress.

As for Qt, they actually offer several pre-built configurations for their reference binary downloads.  Because, at least on Windows, the MSVCRT (C-runtime APIs from Visual Studio) are closely tied to different compiler versions of Visual Studio. So they offer various downloads to match the configuration you want to build your your code for (32-bit, 64-bit, VS2017, VS2019, etc...).  So when you put together a complete application with 3rd party dependencies, some of these build, linkage, and CPU/OS configs have to be accounted for.